# URL Parameters - Encoding

Tags: php, encryption

Just looking for some advice over a feature I am currently working on.  I am building on top of a custom e-commerce site and to increase conversions etc. I want to be able to send a URL to customers that is encoded with their details so that I can identify them when they arrive on the site.

For example

customer_id=1&offer_id=50&sale_products=1,2,3,4&promoted_product=12&agent=99

From this query string I can query the database and get:

- the customer details from their id
- which special offer to display i.e. 20% of products
- Which products are on sale for them
- promoted product to display on the landing page
- who the referrer / agent was so we can show the partner logo

I could use 2 way encryption to encrypt / decrypt this (was thinking to encode the whole query string as one item) and then I would be able to use the parameters and variables, but I would have to split then and check which were there. Not all the vars are required.

But got a bad feeling over this it's almost obscurity and not secure (don't know why, it just does not feel right... and that there is a better way to do this....)

Can anyone see if this is a good way to achieve this or think of a better way...

Thanks

Comment: To quote Han Solo .... "I've got a bad feeling about this" ... implicitly trust **nothing** in your `$_GET` data; you'd be better off just setting that all up in the database and retrieving it only when the user logs in.

Comment: haha  - yep trust nothing, all the vars will be validated to ensure they are sanitised and I have a user token that validates that user_id belongs to that token.

Other item I was think of doing has guid style url 463454-3242342-234234-32242 and each part of the sting represented a different var.   

Quite unfair to just vote the question down though...

Comment: Wasn't actually me that voted it down - I only generally vote down "lazy" questions (e.g. anything that can be answered with RTFM) :)